# Is the Projectivization of a coherent sheaf on a reduced Noetherian scheme reduced again?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a reduced Noetherian scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. What i am wondering is:

> Is it true or not that the projectivization $$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})=\underline{\mathrm{Proj}}(\underline{\mathrm{Sym}}(\mathcal{F}))$$ is reduced again?

If this has any influence on the question: In the case i want to consider, $X$ is actually a smooth, projective variety over an algebraically closed field.

EDIT: Removed a previous thought of mine including a mistake...

Finally one follow-up question: In case of a negative answer, are there easy conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ to assure reducedness of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The (homogeneous) ideals generated by linear forms are prime. This is easily seen if recall the isomorphism $R[X]/(X+a)\simeq R$, $a\in R$.

Comment: "the question [...] is equivalent to whether  [...] the symmetric algebra Sym(M) is reduced again" - just its homogeneous localizations at homogeneous elements of positive degree, right? If Sym(M) is reduced, then clearly the (homogeneous) localizations are reduced, but the converse is not clear to me.

Comment: You have to be very careful as for exact sequences of algebras, since the category of algebras has no zero object, it has no sums of morphisms etc. What is correct is that $\mathrm{Sym}(M)$ is the *coequalizer* of the two maps $Sym(A) \to Sym(B)$, one being induced by the chosen map $A \to B$, the other being induced by the zero map $0 : A \to B$. Notice that $Sym(A) \to Sym(B)$ induced by $0 : A \to B$ is not the zero map, it is rather given by $Sym(A) \to R \to Sym(B)$, where the first map kills the elements of $A$ and the second one is the unit.

Comment: @user26857: Well but our polynomials don't have to be monic. A typical example for a symmetric algebra is $Z[x,y]/(2x+3y)$. How do you simplify it?

Comment: Maybe that $R$ is a field. If not, then what I said is not true.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: @user26857: Thank you very much for your comments! Actually i thought -- in the situation where $X$ is a variety, so $R$ is integral -- about imbedding $R$ into its field of fractions, but unfortunately i didn't get any further from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric algebras of $R$-modules are precisely the ones which have a presentation (as a commutative $R$-algebra) in which every relation is a polynomial of degree $\leq 1$. An example is $\mathrm{Sym}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/4)=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(4x)$. This is not reduced since $(2x)^2=0$. Notice that $\mathrm{Proj}\bigl(\mathrm{Sym}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/4)\bigr)$ is actually affine, namely $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(4x)_{(x)})$ where the subscript $(x)$ denotes the homogeneous localization at the *element* $x$ (in your answer you forgot to distinguish between the algebra and its homogeneous localizations; this is the big difference between $\mathrm{Spec}$ and $\mathrm{Proj}$). Notice that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(4x)_{(x)} = \mathbb{Z}/4$ as rings and this is still not reduced. The same reasoning shows for arbitrary ideals $I \subseteq R$ that $\mathrm{Proj}\bigl(\mathrm{Sym}_R(R/I)\bigr)=\mathrm{Spec}(R/I)$ and this is reduced if and only if $I$ is a radical ideal.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! According to the distinction between homogeneous localizations and the algebra -- i hope this isn't a stupid thought of mine, but i thought reducedness from one implied reducedness for the other, for if all homogeneous localizations were reduced, then the corresponding direct limit and thus the homogeneous localization at every (homogeneous) prime was irreducible -- and then i planed to use the fact that reducedness is a stalk-local property...

Comment: Yes that direction is clear, but the other one is not: $\mathrm{Proj}(A)$ is reduced iff all homogeneous localizations of $A$ are reduced, but there is no reason (I think...) why this should imply that $A$ itsself is reduced.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, of course you're right!

Comment: About the follow-up question at the lower end of my post -- is there any "straight-forward" condition one could impose on $\mathcal{F}$ (resp. $M$) to get reducedness of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})$ after all?